# Grafana Singlestat showing same value for different panels on repeating row

Tags: postgresql, grafana, grafana-templating

I created a value series and use it to take a list of values from a postgresql DB.. But when I select any value from the series, they return the same values for all the singlestat at the repeating row... Anything I did wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?